# How can I add a custom field?

Tags: paragraphs, 10

I am using layout paragraph module. I have a "section" paragraph with the layout paragraph behaviour. I want to add a field Background color to the section.

Should I add it inside the layout configuration form in the same way  https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/layout-api/how-to-register-layouts adds a textfield, or should I add the background color field to the "section" paragraph?

Comment: If this field is never meant to be really printed to the user or to be translated, use a behavior plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest adding the fields to the **section** paragraph type.

I've done something similar in the past by adding colour fields (foreground/background) and other properties (margin/padding) to the section paragraph type.

This way you can keep your layouts purely structural, and define all styling on section level, regardless of the chosen layout.

Comment: Thank You so much for this clear explanation :)

Comment: If this field is never meant to be really printed to the user or to be translated, use a behavior plugin instead.

Comment: @leymannx thanks for your comment ! But  could you please tell me what is a "behavior plugin" ? Or could you give me a link to read about it ?

Comment: @leymannx I finally opted for adding fields in section paragraoh because i want to add the section title field as well and it translatable so I added it to the section paragraph, I would like to thank you for pointing out to the translation point because that's what made me choose this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Style Options Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/style_options) was designed just for this purpose by the same team. It's used with their Mercury Editor, but it was designed to separate out these types of style related options from the content of the paragraphs.

Comment: Thank You for this clear answer !